# Why we cannot import PIL and call Image?

Tags: python, image

```
from PIL import Image
n=Image.new('RGBA',(200,200),'white')
```

works fine but,

```
import PIL
n=PIL.Image.new('RGBA',(200,200),'white')
```

Gives AttributeError

Comment: Because that's the way packages work in Python.

Comment: probably `Image` is a file, not class in file `PIL`

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that all the modules that permit:

```
import PIL
PIL.Image
```

Where `Image` is the module in the `PIL` package have a `__init__.py` that imports all the modules in the package. Those would contain the statement:

```
import Image
# and so forth for the rest of the package's modules
```

That is because `PIL.Image` does not refer to the module `Image` in the package `PIL` but rather the property `Image` of the module `PIL`

But PIL does not do so to import one of the modules in the package you either need to use:

```
from PIL import Image
```

or

```
import PIL.Image as Image
```